# Debug android app that's NOT in Play Store (Log Collecting)

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

I have released an Android application to about 5-10 people who are close friends of mine to test it out. I just sent them my .apk file. The problem is, when it crashes (happening often, as I'm early in development) I have no way to look at the logs. If I had released the application to Google Play, they would be able to press "Send Error Report" which I could then see in my Google Play developer account. Is there any easy way to get logs from these crashes in this sort of third party application development environment?

The only thing I can think of is to have them install [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) and just send me a log. But that's pretty cumbersome, obviously. Especially for a non tech user.

Comment: aLogcat doesn't work on newer phones.

Comment: in what sense does it not work?

Comment: On my GNex atleast it doesnt report anything useful. I just removed it for that very reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Application Crash Report for Android http://acra.ch/

Since the Google Docs legacy forms is completly discontinued http://www.bugsense.com/docs/android#acra seems to be a good option as backend.

Comment: This looks like an interesting option. Do you have any affiliation with this service?

Comment: @unexpected62 while I don't know whether Richard has any affiliations with ACRA, it's a popular tool that's in fairly widespread use.

Comment: Sadly google discontinued the use of forms so you have to report somewhere else other than there. No real clue where right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could publish it on the play store, and `Unpublish` it. This way you could use the same functionality, while no having unwanted people stumble upon it.

When you feel the app is ready, you could simply publish it again.

EDIT:

Note that `Unpublish` will not remove your app from the store, it will simply make it not visible, but with a URL you can still browse to the play store listing.

EDIT 2:

To view the `Unpublished` app, append your package id:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_id>
```

Comment: So if I unpublish, the URL is actually still live for me to send to people, is that correct?